# How to reload the page on the scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to reload a page on the scroll event, the condition works with other methods but not with the `window.location.reload()`

Why is this not functioning as intended?

```
var $searchBox = $('#searchBox');
var $the = $(window);
$the.on('resize', function() {
   if($searchBox.is(':focus')) {
      if($the.width() > 940) {
         window.location.reload(true);

      };
   }
});
```

Comment: here it worked fine... try  if($the.width() > 940) { alert() }

Comment: the condition works fine i tryed already .alert() only the reload does not seem to work.

Comment: What's this the after $ meaning? Ref to some dom obj?

Comment: I have updated the post to explain the $the

Comment: Are there any alerts or errors in the console?

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/44qeuof3/1/), also note that if the browser remembers the scroll location this will be triggered when the page is reloaded as well, causing the page to reload in an infinite loop. And your title is misleading as this function is run on resize, not on scroll.

Comment: `resize` is not `scroll` event.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have 50 reputation so I have to use the answer field.

I uploaded the code here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kqz9r7f/2/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox" />
```

CSS:

```
#searchBox {
    width: 100%;
}

#searchBox:focus {
    background: #000;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var $searchBox = $('#searchBox');
var $the = $(window);
$the.on('resize', function() {
   if($searchBox.is(':focus')) {
      if($the.width() > 940) {
         // alert('page will be reloading');
         window.location.reload(true);

      };
   }
});
```

Your code works fine if you focus the input box and then pull the left border to the left side so your page is bigger than 940px. There won't be a loop because the field has to be focused.

Comment: this is not true because if I do only alert() then I do get the alert, but not the reload.

Comment: If you dont call the function to reload then there won't be a reload. If you call the alert and then the reload function the page will reload after you closed the alert.